# Using the YADCF datatable plugin with Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, datatables, yadcf

I'm using the recommended custom bindings to get the datatables to bind with knockout, however, I've been struggling to get the YADCF plugin to function.  It runs with no errors but fails to display anything.  I've tested with just a straight forward html table and it seems to run fine and the filters show.  I tried putting the YADCF init function in the init and update functions of the knockout binding to no avail.  Does anyone know how to properly get this to function? Can't seem to find any reference to getting these three to play well.

YADCF Version: 0.9.1

DataTables Version: 1.10.15

Knockout Version: 3.4.0

Require Version: 2.2.0

```
<tbody data-bind="dataTablesForEach: { data: SubDetails, options: { destroy: true, bAutoWidth: false } }">

ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach = {
            page: 0,                
            init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                var binding = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                ko.unwrap(binding.data);
                if (binding.options.paging) {
                    binding.data.subscribe(function(changes) {
                        var t = $(element).closest('table');
                        var table = t.DataTable();                     
                        ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page = table.page();
                        table.destroy();
                    }, null, 'arrayChange');
                }
                var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.childNodes, 0);
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(nodes, function(node) {
                    if (node && node.nodeType !== 1) { node.parentNode.removeChild(node); }
                });                     

                return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
            },
            update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                var binding = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()), key = 'DataTablesForEach_Initialized';
                ko.unwrap(binding.data);
                var table;
                if (!binding.options.paging) {
                    table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable();
                    table.destroy();
                }
                ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
                var t = $(element).closest('table');
                d_table = t.DataTable(binding.options);      
                YADCF.init(d_table, [
                        {
                            column_number: 1,
                            filter_type: "multi_select",
                            select_type: 'chosen'
                        }
                    ]);                                                
                if (binding.options.paging) {
                    if (t.page.info().pages - ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page === 0) {
                        t.page(--ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page).draw(false);
                    } else {
                        t.page(ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page).draw(false);
                    }
                }

                if (!ko.utils.domData.get(element, key) && (binding.data || binding.length)) {
                    ko.utils.domData.set(element, key, true);
                }                                        

                return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
            }
        };
```

Comment: please show the datatables init code and yadcf init code, and specify versions of both plugins

Comment: @Daniel I've updated it with the versions and how I attempted to initialize the plugin.  I've tried it both with and without the chosen specifier.  The d_table variable is declared outside of the scope of this function.

Comment: I managed to throw together a jsfiddle without require and it seems to be working fine.  Do you know of any issues or special requirements that YADCF needs to work with require.js?

Comment: Please try the latest beta of yadcf

Comment: That solved it.  Thanks so much @Daniel!